# browse.FileName doesn't set my string variable

Tags: c#, winforms, filenames, openfiledialog

So I'm currently creating a quiz for coursework and originally I had all my questions inside of txt files. I am now in the process of putting the questions in one binary file. To make this easier upon myself I'm trying to make a converter button which will set a string variable to the path of the txt file but it just won't assign itself.

```
        string file_name;

        OpenFileDialog browse = new OpenFileDialog();
        browse.Filter = "Choose Questions to import(*.txt;)|*.txt";

        if (browse.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            file_name = browse.FileName;
        }

        System.IO.StreamReader txtReader;
        txtReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_name);
```

Comment: Time to use the debugger. Put a breakpoint inside the if and check the value of browse.FileName.

Comment: @Steve ah well there was already an error so the program wouldn't load anyways, but thanks anways for the response.

Comment: By the way, the code above doesn't compile if you don't set string file_name to an initial value

Comment: As suspected. The problem is in the failed initialization of _file_name_ Set it to an empty string when you declare it. And follow the advice in the answer below.

Comment: that did the trick, damn why didn't i see that. Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you should be doing all the code inside the OK portion.

Otherwise, if they cancel, it'll throw an error.

You also want to use a USING statement to read files so it disposes of resources.

browse.FileName works.

```
    OpenFileDialog browse = new OpenFileDialog();
    browse.Filter = "Choose Questions to import(*.txt;)|*.txt";

    if (browse.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string file_name = browse.FileName;

        using (System.IO.StreamReader txtReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_name))
        {

            // Do Your File Manipulation Here!

        }
    }
```